# Infinite while loop when reading file

Tags: c, file, infinite-loop

I am getting an infinite loop (in while loop) with this function. I am new to working with files, so I feel like I am missing something...I can't see what is wrong.

```
void cipher(FILE* password_ptr,int n)
{    
        if (password_ptr == NULL)
        {
                printf("Error:password_ptr points to null");
                return;
        }
        while(!feof(password_ptr))
        {
                fseek(password_ptr, 0, SEEK_CUR); // don't move
                int en=fgetc(password_ptr)+n;

                fseek(password_ptr, -1, SEEK_CUR); // move backwards one character
                if(fputc(en,password_ptr)!=en)
                {
                printf("Error:fputc didn't work");
                }
                fseek(password_ptr, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        fclose(password_ptr);
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you `fseek`ing to not move in the first place?

Comment: your own code comments tell you why - apply 1st to the last fseek if you really cannot see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A side effect of calling `fseek()` is that the EOF indication on the file gets cleared:

C99 7.19.9.2/5 The fseek function:

> After determining the new position, a successful call to the fseek function undoes any effects of the ungetc function on the stream, ***clears the end-of-ﬁle indicator*** for the stream, and then establishes the new position.

Note that your code also uses the common anti-pattern of a loop controlled by the `feof()` function. That function will not return `EOF` until *after* an I/O operation gets you to that point (sets the end-of-file indicator).  In other words, even when you enter the loop, the `fgetc()` may fail due to being at the end of the file (that's what will set the end-of-file indicator). But then a subsequent seek will clear that indicator.  In the meantime, you'll have operated on the `EOF` as if it were a normal, successful read.

See:

- [Common C Programming Errors: Using feof() incorrectly](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2)
- ["while( !feof( file ) )" is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/12711)

You might want to try the following loop instead:

```
int c;
while((c = fgetc(password_ptr)) != EOF)
{
    int en= c+n;

    fseek(password_ptr, -1, SEEK_CUR); // move backwards one character
    if(fputc(en,password_ptr)!=en)
    {
        printf("Error:fputc didn't work");
        break;
    }
}
```

You also need to think about how you want this bit of code to handle a situation where `en` is out of the range of an `unsigned char`.  Since `fputc()` converts the character to be written to an `unsigned char` before writing it to the stream, if `en` is outside of that range the "fputc didn't work" error will be displayed. This might happen, for example, if adding `n` to the character read by `fgetc()` is larger than 255.

Comment: @spatara: Note: my original suggested fix had `c` declared as an `int`, which might result in `EOF` not being detected (another common bug with handling `EOF`) - `c` should be an `int` type to make sure `EOF` is properly detected.